# Quotient group if and only if

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-spaces

My textbook says

$uN=vN$ if and only if $v^{-1}$ such that $u \in \mathbb{N}$

What is the if and only if relation for right cosets
$Nu=Nv$? If and only if $v \times u^{-1} \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, that is the relation for right cosets.

Answer (score 1):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $Nu=Nv$
- $Nuv^{-1}=N$
- $uv^{-1}\in N$
- $N=Nvu^{-1}$
- $vu^{-1}\in N$